# Wait time for synchronous camel route

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, esb

I am utilizing an external API for my internal flow but it seems external service took more than a minute to respond. I have set an internal timeout for the complete flow but external service still progressing request. So my internal timeout triggered and generic error has been shown to the user.

So is there any way to set response wait time for a camel route???

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: both seda and direct endpoints have `timeout` properties you can configure

Comment: i can't find any documentation for it. If u have please help me

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/direct.html

Comment: In my case, Consumer also presents in a camel context. As per docs, It clearly says if no consumer available trigger timeout.

Comment: You should flesh out your question with more detail. and code.